# error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '->'

Tags: visual-c++

In the program below I am getting following errors:

```
error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '->'  
error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '->'
```

Any guess where I am doing wrong?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#using <system.drawing.dll>
using namespace System;
using namespace System::Drawing;
int main()
{       
Image^ newImage = Image::FromFile( "SampImag.jpg" );
// Create parallelogram for drawing image.
Point ulCorner = Point(100,100);
Point urCorner = Point(325,100);
Point llCorner = Point(150,250);
array<Point>^ destPara = {ulCorner,urCorner,llCorner};
// Create rectangle for source image.
Rectangle srcRect = Rectangle(50,50,150,150);
GraphicsUnit units = GraphicsUnit::Pixel;
// Draw image to screen.
    //Graphics1 = new Graphics();  
     Graphics->DrawImage( newImage, destPara, srcRect, units );
   return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Hint: What is `Graphics` supposed to be?

Comment: Graphics is a class, having a member function DrawImage, I have to access this function

Comment: Is `DrawImage` a static method of class `Graphics`?

Comment: I think no, as I could not find in the documentation

Comment: @gpuguy What line are you getting this error?

Comment: Graphics->DrawImage( newImage, destPara, srcRect, units );

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you can call DrawImage only on an instance of Graphics class.

But the probem is that Graphics class is an abstract class and Console application does not have an associated Graphics object. [This MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5y289054%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) gives some information on how to use Graphics class. First create a working C# console app with Graphics class and then translate it to C++/CLI. This would be easier way to tackle this issue.

In case you are allowed to, try using VS 2012 to create the C++/CLI application as it provides intellisense for C++/CLI projects.

Comment: This gave error: error C2512: 'System::Drawing::Graphics::Graphics' : no appropriate default constructor available

Comment: @gpuguy Correct. I did not compile it :)

Comment: @gpuguy Please have a look at my modified answer